# Change FlipClock duration seconds timer setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, flipclock

I have FlipClock code as following

```
 var clockDuration = $('.clock-duration').FlipClock({
        // ... your options here
    });
```

Clock working fine but I have requirement as follows

For e.x - **Normally Clock start as 00:00(mm:ss)  and after 60 seconds it shows 00:59(mm:ss) and after that it will change minute 01:00(mm:ss) but I want change this when clock start it should be started as 00:01 and after 60 seconds it should shown as 00:60 and after that 01:00**

Basically I need to change FlipClock start and end seconds setting

Can you please help me out from this stuck?

I refer following site for this but not found solution for this

[FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/)

Comment: Looking at the options, try passing `minimumDigits(int) - The number of minimum digits to display on the clock face. The default value is 0.`, which might solve your first issue

Comment: That's not how clocks work, at least not where I live, so I don't think you can use the API for that.

Answer (score 0):

With such requirements I can see only 4 solutions:

1. Change core code of FlipClock javascript file.
2. Make javascript callback funcion on seconds change in FlipClock and change text in time block manually. It's pretty complex with many exeptions that will be finded.
3. As you want to show after 60 seconds time: 00:60 and then 01:00, so you want in 1 second show 2 seconds... **That's very strange behavior that makes no sense and no real profit. Best solution - give up in this idea, because it will cost much time with bad results in the end**.
4. Make your own timer.

I think 3 is best. Next best is 4 alternative.